# Using Azure to automatically scale horizontally

Tags: azure, deployment, scaling

We're looking at options for the architecture of our Azure Sitecore solution and want to ensure the following:

- We can configure the solution to automatically scale horizontally (spin up new delivery servers) based on a threshold rule
- Maintain two Web databases; Web1 and Web2
- Ensure that half of our delivery servers point to the Web1 database and the other half point to the Web2 database

Could anyone let us know how we can achieve the above? Could we use Azure 'Scale Sets' and if so how could we achieve the alternate connection string configuration when scaling automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic scenario, you can set up the following:

- 1 Traffic Manager (TM)
- 2 Web Apps of Sitecore CD server behind the TM (one pointing Web1, another pointing Web2)

Then, each Web App can be configured for further horizontal scaling in the Azure portal (via Scale Out feature). It allows up to 10 instances for each web app.

Read more:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-how-to-scale